# Hide a band in stimulsoft report based on condition

Tags: stimulsoft

I have a report with stimulsoft.
This report consists of 3 bands, how can I hide a band based on field data(i.e ID is null) at run time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the **Conditions**. Specify an expression when the band should be hidden and uncheck the **Component is Enabled** option there.